# MYSQL : SELECT DISTINCT JOIN tables and ORDER BY DESC don't work correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

This request returns a result `ORDER BY d.createdAt`, and I want a result `ORDER BY m.createdAt`

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.id, d.*
  FROM discussion d
  JOIN message m
    ON d.id = m.discussion_id
 WHERE d.deletedAt IS NULL
   AND (d.sender_id = 4 OR d.receiver_id = 4)
 ORDER BY m.createdAt DESC limit 0, 12
```

Thanks.

Comment: When SELECT DISTINCT, you can only ORDER BY columns you select. (Makes sense.)

Comment: If you do GROUP BY, you can order by the first (or last) message.

Answer (score 0):

As jarlh already commented you cannot order by a column you do not select. So you need to group by discussion and order it by the newest message per discussion like this:

```
SELECT d.id, max(m.createdAt)
  FROM discussion d
  JOIN message m
    ON d.id = m.discussion_id
 WHERE d.deletedAt IS NULL
   AND (d.sender_id = 4 OR d.receiver_id = 4)
 GROUP BY d.id
 ORDER BY max(m.createdAt) DESC limit 0, 12
```

Comment: Thank you, but this returns same result ORDER BY d.createdAt.

Comment: This highly depends on your data. Just create a message for an old discussion to get it on top again (which will not happen if you order by d.createdAt).

Comment: I've just fixed my answer to use `ORDER BY max(m.createdAt)` instead of `ORDER BY m.createdAt` which is not even possible afaik.